# Cannot edit or delete rows of MS Access tables linked from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with MS Access front-end (linked ODBC tables). I can see all linked tables in MS Access and can add new rows.

However, when trying to update or delete existing data, I get this error:

> Process is stopped by Microsoft Jet because multiple users are trying to edit the same data simultaneously.

There are no multiple users, the table has a primary key on an integer column, and has no bit columns (these all are possible reasons of the similar issues I found on the related forums).

What could be reason of the issue?

I tried to delete and create again linked table in MS Access. Also, I verified that the 'problem' table has primary key over integer column and has no bit columns that could be reason of the issue according to advises on related forums.

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent driver? Jet was replaced back in 2007. Are you really still using something like Access 2003? *Not to mention 2008 R2 ran* completely *out of support in 2019.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several common reasons for this.

Most common is a bit (true/false in Access) column that allows nulls. This will trigger the "dreaded" this record been updated by someone else.

The other common issue is the table in question has some kind of delete trigger.

So, to fix this issue:

Make sure the table(s) in question have a PK value. Again, Access allows tables to not have a PK, but linked tables to SQL server require a PK column.

Next up, make sure any/all of the SQL bit columns have a default value of 0 setup, and DO NOT allow nulls for SQL bit columns.

Next up, add a time stamp column to the table(s) in question. Now, while "time stamp" sounds like it has something to do with time, it does not! Hence, the worlds WORST name in history for a column type. The correct "term" is called a row version column, and thankfully over the years, Microsoft is slowly changing the term used for such columns.

So, fix any null bit columns (run an update for any null values to be set = 0). and in SQL table design, set the default value for the bit column to be 0, and not allow nulls.

Add the time stamp column, and then re-link all of your tables.

At this point, you should be able to delete row/records from the Access client.

Since you note no bit columns, the error can still occur due to floating point columns and rounding errors. With such rounding errors, then Access will "think" the record been changed when it has not been. Introduction of a row version (timestamp) column will fix this error, since now Access will NOT resort to a column by column compare of the record to determine if changes have occurred (by you, or someone else). And with floating point rounding errors, then the column by column compare fails. Introduction of a row version column eliminates this column by column compare.

So, introduction of a row version column should fix this error.

Also, avoid using datetime2 columns, and if your table(s) in question have a datetime2 columns, then you need to use the newer ODBC drivers (NC 11 or later).

Note that after adding the timestamp (row version) column, then you need to re-link the tables in Access.

Comment: Why do you even introduce the term `timestamp`? You're just adding to the confusion and shooting yourself in the foot. Call it a `rowversion` column, as it is correctly named in the documentation, and don't even mention `timestamp` - problem solved.

Comment: Well because  in the sql designer the column type you select is called timestamp. As I stated it's a bad name for a column which behind the scenes is a incrementing big Integer data type.  So while timestamp is a really bad name it's still what you will use and select in the SQL table designer.  Not my fault that's the column name type you will use and select as such

Comment: Interesting, but who uses the table designer?

Comment: Golly,  I use it multiple times per day. So for those looking for the correct type in the SQL server table designer,  then yes from the column type you select timestamp. Can't imagine that most would type in DDL sql statements?

Comment: From the comments I see here (and my own experience) I think most people who do any significant work in SQL Server end up scripting everything. Its faster and your have full control.

Comment: Sure,  but even then the type you choose in scripting will be of timestamp. So once again we back to choosing a column type that's miss leading,  right?

Comment: No, when you script it you use `rowversion` :) but I understand why you talk about timestamp given (very surprising) its the only option in the designer - thats a bit of an oversight by MS, trying to depreciate a type while forcing you to keep using it.

Comment: You have to define what you mean when scriptiing a table - we talking about table design here - even if you using DDL statements? Try this: SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Bookings'

Comment: Once again in the above schema query, the data_type returned is timestamp, and we don't see rowversion. So, no, this is not a UI issue limited to ONLY SSMS, you will see, will note, will find and experience the data_type of timesamp when using sql statements. In fact, if you script out a table, the script shows and uses timestamp. In other words timestamp still a valid data_type, and even worse is that if you use sql server scripting tools, the data type you see again is timestamp.  So EVEN when scripting you see timestamp as type, and thus this is not limited to just UI + table designer.

Comment: *"Can't imagine that most would type in DDL sql statements?"* Most people ***do***; my personal suggestion is to forget the "feature" exists or treat it as deprecated (which based on its treatment ove the last 20 years I'd suggest it unofficially is). The designer is outdated, lacks support for many features added in "modern" versions (read 2008/2012 onwards), quirky, and buggy. That it uses `timestamp` and not `rowversion` is just an excellent example of how outdated it is, as `timestamp` was deprecated in **2008**.

Comment: Thanks for ALL answers. Adding timestamp column resolved the issue.

Comment: @ThomA -- as I stated, your points would be valid IF ONLY the GUI designer has/had this issue. Even when you script out the table you see timestamp. So in 100% command line environment a query of schema? Once again, you see/get timestamp as the column type. Too bad this issue is not limited to the GUI and table designer. In an 100% command line and scripting environment the column type of timestamp pops up all the time.  We can wish and scream this issue was limited to the GUI - but it it not!!!. So even dumping the GUI, we still have this issue with a simple schema query.

Comment: My point is still valid, @AlbertD.Kallal . The designer is ***bad*** and *outdated*.

Comment: Fine, but it changes little if anything in terms of solving the issue of seeing the column type as timestamp.  So, some opinion on the GUI really does not matter, nor does it change the fact that EVEN with command line tools, the data type returned is timestamp and not rowversion. So, then by simple logic avoiding the GUI does not address nor solve this issue, does it?

Comment: It's not an opinion, @AlbertD.Kallal .

Comment: it is most certainly your opinion that hoards of developers don't use the GUI or should not. My work experience on multiple companies in multiple countries says otherwise. But here's the big rub: Even if we did accept your limited opinion on use of the GUI designer? it still don't help, still don't change that even with command line tools - the schema returns timestamp, and not rowversion. EVEN when you create the column using rowversion, a schema query still returns timesamp!   So, really, either way your suggesting does not help nor address that we have to deal with column type of timestamp.